# Undefined Reference errors when using IL2CPP in Unity

Tags: il2cpp

after switching unity scripting to IL2CPP scripting my android build is gettting a lot of undefined reference errors.  A lot of them reference to IOS ARKit related stuff.  Can i use #if !UNITY_IOS statements to remove them from my android build ?  and where can i put these #if statements ?

errors are realated to Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_8.cpp.. i tried putting @if statements in it for platform specific build but does not seem to make a difference

## if !UNITY_IOS

```
public class ARFaceAnchor 
{
    private UnityARFaceAnchorData faceAnchorData;
    private static Dictionary<string, float> blendshapesDictionary;

    public ARFaceAnchor (UnityARFaceAnchorData ufad)
    {
        faceAnchorData = ufad;
        if (blendshapesDictionary == null) {
            blendshapesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, float> ();
        }
    }


    public string identifierStr { get { return faceAnchorData.identifierStr; } }

    public Matrix4x4 transform { 
        get { 
            Matrix4x4 matrix = new Matrix4x4 ();
            matrix.SetColumn (0, faceAnchorData.transform.column0);
            matrix.SetColumn (1, faceAnchorData.transform.column1);
            matrix.SetColumn (2, faceAnchorData.transform.column2);
            matrix.SetColumn (3, faceAnchorData.transform.column3);
            return matrix;
        }
    }


    public ARFaceGeometry faceGeometry { get { return new ARFaceGeometry (faceAnchorData.faceGeometry); } }

    public Dictionary<string, float> blendShapes { get { return GetBlendShapesFromNative(faceAnchorData.blendShapes); } }

    delegate void DictionaryVisitorHandler(IntPtr keyPtr, float value);

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void GetBlendShapesInfo(IntPtr ptrDic, DictionaryVisitorHandler handler);

    Dictionary<string, float> GetBlendShapesFromNative(IntPtr blendShapesPtr)
    {
        blendshapesDictionary.Clear ();
        GetBlendShapesInfo (blendShapesPtr, AddElementToManagedDictionary);
        return blendshapesDictionary;
    }

    [MonoPInvokeCallback(typeof(DictionaryVisitorHandler))]
    static void AddElementToManagedDictionary(IntPtr keyPtr, float value)
    {
        string key = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(keyPtr);
        blendshapesDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

## endif

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove from Android build, use

```
#if !UNITY_ANDROID
       // your code here
#endif
```

Will be more helpful if you can post your error message is pertaining to which line.

Comment: Thanks Darren, manage to build 64bit .  but now the camera wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Darren,

i must have got it all wrong.  so

## if !UNITY_ANDROID means if NOT Android ?

Comment: yup
sorry couldn't add comment previously